# Select on socket and stdin

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm experimenting with select and have a simple app that writes, whatever the user entered in the command line, to a server. The server then echoes it back. I'm using the select function to listen on the connected socket and stdin.

Client code:

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
char *readArr = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
fd_set rset;
ssize_t n;
string input;
FD_ZERO(&rset);
while(true){
  FD_SET(socketFD[0], &rset);
  FD_SET(0, &rset);

  maxfpd1 = max(socketFD[0], 0) + 1;
  select(maxfpd1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if(FD_ISSET(0, &rset)){
    cin>>input;
    write(socketFD[0], input.c_str(), input.size());
    cout<<"\nSocket write!\n";
  }
  if(FD_ISSET(socketFD[0], &rset)){
    n = read(socketFD[0], readArr, BUFFER_SIZE-1);
    readArr[n] = '\0';
    cout<<"\nSocket read!\n";
    cout<<readArr;
  }
}
```

Now, if I type "Hello!" in the command line and hit enter, I get this output:

```
Hello! //User input

Socket write!//Client output

Socket read!//Client output
```

If I hit enter again, "Hello!" is printed. Why do I need to hit enter twice?

I can see from the server output that after the first enter the message is sent correctly to the server, and then back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin>>input` does not read the newline from the end of the line, and `cout<<readArr` does not write a newline.  If you use `cout<<readArr<<endl` it will write a newline after the string and flush the output buffer.  If you don't want a newline after your string you can use `flush` instead of `endl` to only flush the output buffer.  You could also change `cout` to unbuffered if you don't want it to buffer your output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cin>>input` doesn't read a whole line, only one word. It won't read the line feed, and if you type two words it won't read the second one. You should probably use `getline(cin,input)` instead, which reads the whole line and puts in in `input` (without the line feed, which is discarded).